# Increment the variable in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I know this question is asked many times. I tried the same as the answer provided for those question. It didn't works for me. I just want to increment a variable if Value of attribute is mentioned twice. i tried the below method which also not works

```
    <xsl:variable name="counter" select="0" saxon:assignable="yes"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="//MARKER/*/*/*">
       <xsl:if test="contains(@Name,'Black' )">
        <saxon:assign name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
        </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

After this also value of counter is zero instead of 2. Can any one suggest me, how to achieve this

Comment: Don't tell us about the technique you want to use, tell us about the problem you want to solve. What is your input and what is your desired output? Then we can tell you the right technique to use for the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you simply count the nodes you are interested in, e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//MARKER/*/*/*[contains(@Name,'Black' )]"/>
```

---

### Added:

> Thanks it works. But generally. How can we increment the variable?

In general, variables in XSLT 1.0 are immutable.

Saxon 6.5 provides an exception to the rule in the form of the `saxon:assignable` and `saxon:assign` extensions. If you were using Saxon 6.5, your attempt would *probably* work - see a demo here: http://xsltransform.net/94hvTzQ

Strictly speaking, it should **not** work like that, because:

1. `xsl:for-each` is not a loop;
2. what happens inside an `xsl:for-each` is out-of-scope for the
   instructions that are outside of it.

For these reasons, attempting to do the same thing in XSLT 2.0 will fail - even though XSLT 2.0 allows you to reassign a variable - see the demo here: http://xsltransform.net/94hvTzQ/1

As you can see, each **instance** of the `xsl:for-each` instruction increments the initial variable by 1, and does so independently of the other instances - proving that `xsl:for-each` is not a loop. At the end, the original variable is returned unchanged, because of the 2nd reason above.

Comment: Thanks it works. But generally. How can we increment the variable?

Comment: @Cool_Binami I have added an explanation to my answer above. Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: For the XSLT 2.0 example you give it's probably more helpful to think of each time round the the `for-each` as declaring a brand new variable that hides the existing variable with the same name that was declared in the parent scope.  It's not really "reassigning" anything - the parent variable still exists, and ceases to be hidden once the `for-each` local scope ends.

Comment: @IanRoberts Well, within the scope of `xsl:for-each` the original variable ceases to exist once it has been reassigned. I don't think there's another way to look at it. Suppose there's no `xsl:for-each` and you simply declare the same variable twice, effectively overwriting the first declaration: would you then say that the second declaration "hides" the variable created by the first one?

Comment: Yes, I would.  [To paraphrase the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#scope-of-variables), the scope of any non-global variable in XSLT consists of all its declaration's following siblings and their descendants, except where it is shadowed by another variable with the same name.

Comment: @IanRoberts Okay, but that's just semantics. A variable, once "shadowed", cannot be "unshadowed" so its supposed existence is purely philosophical (not that there's anything wrong with that).